# How to enable hardware support for libEGL for Tegra 2 Linux?

Tags: linux, opengl-es, tegra

I am trying to run my OpenGL ES application Ubuntu 11.04 installed on Harmony developer board (Tegra 2), however when I use packages:

```
libegl1-mesa, libegl1-mesa-dev, libegl1-mesa-drivers
libgles2-mesa, libgles2-mesa-dev
```

application reports:

```
libEGL warning using software fallback
```

I was getting the same message when I tried to start example provided in package mesa-utils-extra called /usr/bin/es2gears but after updating drivers:

```
export LDK_ROOTFS_DIR=/
cd Linux_for_Tegra
./apply_binaries.sh
```

and creating symlinks like in "Tegra Linux Driver Package Developers Guide"

```
mv /usr/lib/libEGL.so /usr/lib/libEGL.so.1
mv /usr/lib/libGLESv2.so /usr/lib/libGLESv2.so.2
ln -s /usr/lib/libEGL.so.1 /usr/lib/libEGL.so
ln -s /usr/lib/libGLESv2.so.2 /usr/lib/libGLESv2.so
```

I am able to start es2gears using hardware acceleration (2x faster).

My question is where can I get development packages that use appropriate libEGL.so and libGLESv2.so libraries so I can compile my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toradex provides Linux Samples for OpenGL ES for the Nvidia Tegra:

http://developer.toradex.com/software-resources/arm-family/linux/source-code/linux-(colibri-t20)-sample-code

The libraries are included in the Linux images:

http://developer.toradex.com/software-resources/arm-family/linux/source-code/linux-(colibri-t20)-openembedded